# Why am I getting 404 error with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Firstly, I have a capital letter on all controllers.

These work - http://localhost/country - http://localhost/afghanistan

But I'm getting 404 error for http://localhost/afghanistan/afcontactus

I tried changing folder & file names for example http://localhost/afghan/afcontact - and that worked. But if I change the original folder & file names it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error is caused by the Controller function name not being the same as the view file name, for example;

```
public function contactus()
{
$this->load->view('afghanistan/afcontactus');
}
```

Should be;

```
public function afcontactus()
{
$this->load->view('afghanistan/afcontactus');
}
```